# Make Windows 10 show hard disk as internal

Tags: windows, windows-10, external-hard-drive

I have used an USB to SATA cable to connect a new SSD to my notebook and copy files to it. Now, when putting it into the DVD-bay using an appropriate adapter (as second drive) it still shows up as external drive. It looks like Windows remembers this drive (even same drive letter is used). How can I make Windows 10 forget about this drive like it would be completely new to this Windows instance - hoping then it would treat it as internal drive?

Comment: What is the "appropriate adapter"? Please add a screenshot from Disk Management.

Comment: I assumed you would know - something like this: https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07TWCNH1K/

Comment: I don't know your motherboard and the connector, but it seems to me that you haven't connected to where the BIOS expects to find an internal disk.

Comment: Couldn't it be because Windows knows that this disk has been connected by USB before?

Comment: Seems unlikely.